# Memory Issues : Shell Scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have 5 files in a folder a.csv b.csv ....

I need to combine these files into one file called X.csv and in future keep merging the contents of X.csv with a,b,c etc.

Even with only two lines in each file I have error message saying that there is not enough memory - its essentially only copying 10 lines across. Im using the following command :

```
 paste -d, *.csv >> X.csv.
```

However when i use

```
 paste -d, *.csv > X.csv
```

There are no memory issues. This however I canont use since i need the information on the X.CSV file previously as well so I should only append not edit contents of the whole file.

Would anyone know how I achieve this? These are ',' separated CSV files and I would like to not copy the header (Row 1) which names the columns more than once.

I use MAC OSX Mavericks 8 GB Ram.

Thank You :)

Comment: Please show us a a.csv and b.csv and X.csv

Comment: Thank You but I am having Similar memory issue with cat as well. cat *.csv > X.csv. I cannot use a..e since some files have slightly different names but its 5 files in total.

Comment: I think you may have a weird file in there. Try `ls -al` and see if there is anything big and odd! Else try rebooting.

Comment: I guess "*.csv" also matches "X.csv" - let the fun begin :)

Comment: Seriously, save your output to a temporary file whose extension is NOT  ".csv" and rename when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

As @loreb said, `*.csv` is matching `X.csv` as well.  You can avoid that using a proper [**globbing variable**](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html), but that depends if your shell is capable of handling that...  I know `bash` can, and you posted your question with the `bash` tag, but you said you are using Mac OSX - well, I guess you can try it anyway.

```
paste -d, [a-z]*.csv >> X.csv
```

That will run the `paste` command for the files named from `a.csv` to `z.csv`, lowercase, so it will not take `X.csv`, which I think is the current problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you intend to imply about OS X and bash. OS X comes with an older version of bash, but it still has extglob. `shopt -s extglob; paste -d, !(X).csv >> X.csv`

Comment: @kojiro, I'm not a OS X user, so I'm not sure if that's ok for its shell or not...  so, better to try than not, but I wasn't implying something bad, by the way :)  - Thanks for clarifying it for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of data, and in the absence of a tool which keeps track of the line number at which processing last stopped in `[a-z].csv` (which I don't think exists) you can use the following process:

1. Ensure that the writing program is not going to write to the CSV files anymore. Some possible ways to do this:

   - Move the files to a read-only filesystem.
   - Stop the file writing program.
   - Somehow force the program to start writing to a new file descriptor.
2. Rename or move the files if necessary to avoid the writer opening them again.
3. Restart the writer if necessary.
4. `paste -d, /temporary_directory/*.csv >> /final_destination/X.csv`